# Not saving inserted core data in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to insert a new object to my core data.
I inserted this way in previous app and it was ok.

Here is the function

```
_appDelegte=[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
self.managedObjectContext = _appDelegte.managedObjectContext;
@try {

Album *album=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[AlbumTable tableName]                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

//Insert Values
album.albumId=albumId;
album.code=code;
album.name=name;
album.facebookAccessToken=facebookAccessToken;
album.facebookExpires=facebookExpires;
album.albumDescription=description;
album.startTime=startTime;
album.endTime=endTime;
album.latitude=latitude;
album.longitude=longitude;
album.placeName=placeName;
album.ownerFacebookId=ownerFacebookId;
album.isWatermark=isWatermark;



return YES;

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Insert exception - %@", exception.description);
    return NO;
}
```

Later in the app' i'm trying to get the object out and it's nil.

```
// initializing NSFetchRequest
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

//Setting Entity to be Queried
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:[AlbumTable tableName] inManagedObjectContext:_appDelegte.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError* error;

// Query on managedObjectContext With Generated fetchRequest
NSArray *fetchedRecords = [_appDelegte.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

// Returning albums as an array
   for (Album *album in fetchedRecords) {
       return album;
   }
return nil;
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is your context inited properly? Does other Core Data functionality work? Do you get anything in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Check if

- Context is not `nil`
- You call `save:` on the context

Other conspicuous points: the following line of code.

```
Album *album=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[AlbumTable tableName]                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

You have a class album table that returns the table name. I would not advise to use something this complicated. Simply use a string `@"Album"`.

and this

```
// Returning albums as an array
   for (Album *album in fetchedRecords) {
       return album;
   }
```

This is **not** returning the albums as an array. It just returns the first album of the array. Make sure that also the fetch situation has a non-`nil`managed object context.